# How to model 2 correlated Geometric Brownian Motions?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Let's say we have 2 GBM processes:
$$S_1(t)=S_1(0)\cdot \exp{(\mu_1t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_1^2t+\sigma_1\cdot W(t))}\text{  and  } S_2(t)=S_2(0)\cdot \exp{(\mu_2t-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_2^2t+\sigma_2\cdot W(t))}$$
such that $\mathbb{E}[dW_1;dW_2]=\rho$.
How can I model them together? Formulas above won't take the correlation into account. Since $S(t)$ are meant to be stock prices, I can look at daily returns directly as:
$$\frac{S(t+1)-S(t)}{S(t)}=\exp{(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2+\sigma \cdot N(0;1))}-1=\exp{(N(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2;\sigma^2))}-1$$
which is close to normal (transposed lognormal in fact). If it was in fact normally distributed then I would use 2-D $N(M;\Sigma)$ with $M=(\mu_1-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_1^2;\mu_2-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_2^2)$ and $\Sigma$ as the covariance matrix. But I want to be precise with the model and not assume (incorectly) that returns are normal if prices are GBM. So I'm struggling on how to include the correlation/covariance in the direct formulas for $S_1,S_2$.

Comment: You seem to have a typo. For GBM you should have $S(t) = S(0)\exp ((\mu - 0.5 \sigma^2) {\color{red} t} + \sigma W(t))$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $B_1$ and $B_2$ be independent Brownian motions. Set $W_1 = B_1$ and $W_2 = \rho B_1 + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} B_2$. Then $W_1$ and $W_2$ are correlated Brownian motions with correlation coefficient $\rho$.

In your model for correlated geometric Brownian motion, you may let $S_1$ be driven by $W_1$ and $S_2$ be driven by $W_2$, to obtain:

$$\begin{align*}
S_1(t) &= S_1(0) \exp \left( (\mu_1 - 0.5\sigma_1^2)t + \sigma_1 W_1(t) \right) \\
S_2(t) &= S_2(0)\exp \left( (\mu_2 - 0.5\sigma_2^2)t + \sigma_2 W_2(t) \right)
\end{align*} \\
$$

Or, in terms of $(B_1, B_2)$,
$$\begin{align*}
S_1(t) &= S_1(0) \exp \left( (\mu_1 - 0.5\sigma_1^2)t + \sigma_1 B_1(t) \right) \\
S_2(t) &= S_2(0)\exp \left( (\mu_2 - 0.5\sigma_2^2)t + \sigma_2 (\rho B_1(t) + \sqrt{1-\rho^2} B_2(t)) \right)
\end{align*} \\
$$

Comment: Thank you :) Two more issues: when simulating $(S_1(t_0);S_2(t_0))$ for some given $t_0$ I will treat $B_1(t_0)$ as a sample from $N(0;t_0)$, do I have to use the exact same sample result for $B_1(t_0)$ in $S_1(t_0)$ and in $S_2(t_0)$? Also: let's say I have historical data of prices I'm about to model. How can I get the $\rho$ from them? Would the correlation between those historical prices be a good assumption for $\rho$ used later in your formulas or do I have to look at correlation between daily difference quotients (returns)?

Comment: @MichałDąbrowski You would need to sample two independent normal random variables $(B_1, B_2)$ and then correlate them using the formula for $(W_1, W_2)$. For estimating the question of estimating $\rho$, it would be best to ask this as a separate question so I can answer in detail. In short, you would want to filter out the driving Brownian motions and then compute $\sum (W_{s^\prime}^1 - W_s^1) (W_{s^\prime}^2 - W_s^2)$, as this is a consistent estimator for the covariation, from which you can read off $\rho$.

Comment: Yeah, it would be something in a form of:
$$W(t)=\frac{\log{\frac{S(t)}{S(0)}}-(\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\cdot t}{\sigma}$$
but I'm not sure what do you mean by $W_s$ and $W_{s'}$, are those indexes of different time moments for example $s'=s+1$? If so then I understand everything, thanks a lot for that :)

Comment: @MichałDąbrowski Yes by $s^\prime$ I mean the successor of $s$ (which could very well be $s+1$).